# Bounded norm of the Hessian on a compact set?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ twice continuously differentiable . It is known that $f''$ is bounded on $[a,b]$, i.e., there exists $M>0$ so that $|f''(x)| < M$.

Is there an equivalent in $\mathbb{R}^n$? i.e., let $X$ be a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ twice continuously differentiable. Is there $M > 0$ so that $\|H(x)\|_2 < M$ for all $x \in X$, where $H(x)$ is the Hessian matrix of $f$ evaluated at $x$? If so, does it depend on $n$?

Comment: Doesn't this all follow from continuity?

Comment: have you studied banach space yet?

Comment: @JayTuma, No, but if you could direct me to the relevant things it will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things i need to use that you may find on internet, hope this is not a problem.

We begin from seeing $\mathbb{R}^{n,n} \cong \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ both from an algebraic and a metrical point of view.

Next, we see $H_f(x) : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^{n,n} \cong \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$. Since $f$ is twice continuosly differentiable, we know that
$$ H_{i,j} = \frac{ \partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j } \quad \textrm{is continuos} \quad \forall i,j \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$$

A [theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Function_to_Product_Space_is_Continuous_iff_Composition_with_Projections_are_Continuous) in topology state that if I have a function $f:X \to Y \times Z$, it is continuos if and only if the projections of $f$ are continuos (i.e. the functions which take only the first or the second component of $f$).

Now, since $H_f$ goes over the products of topological spaces ($\mathbb{R} \times \ldots \times \mathbb{R} \quad n^2$ times) it is continuos if it's proiections are continuos, but the entries of $H_f$ are the continuos functions $H_{i,j}$. So $H_f$ is continuos.

To conclude, let $X$ be the compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. $H_f$ continuos implies $H_f(X)$ is a compact and so a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n,n}$. So by the definition, there exists $M > 0$ such that
$$ \forall x \in X \quad ||H_f(x)||_2 \leq M $$